# how do i get the first parent that matches a class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab the first parent element that matches a class check, but I'm having problems. My page could look like this:

```
<input id="hidden1" type="hidden" value="5" class="includeds">
<h3>header</h3>
<ul class="groups">
    <li><input id="li1" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li2" type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li3" type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="value()"></li>
</ul>
<input id="hidden2" type="hidden" value="3" class="includeds">
<h3>header2</h3>
<ul class="groups">
    <li><input id="li4" type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li5" type="checkbox" value="5" onclick="value()"></li>
    <li><input id="li6" type="checkbox" value="6" onclick="value()"></li>
</ul>
```

So if I click on checkbox `li1`, I want to retrieve the value `"5"` from the hidden field above it.

If I click `li5`, I want to get the value of `"2"` from the first hidden field above it, etc, etc.

I'm trying this (inside the value() function), but it's not working, I keep receiving an undefined error.

```
var thevalue = $(this).closest(".includeds").value);
```

or

```
var thevalue = $(this).closest(".includeds").attr("value").toString());
```

I don't understand why they aren't working, any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, for one your hidden inputs are NOT parents of the checkboxes. The only parent of the checkbox li5 in the html you've posted is <ul class="groups">. To find them you would have to manually traverse the tree and on every level check for siblings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this working with your markup:

```
var value = $(this).closest('ul').prevAll('.includeds:first').val();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xfE8B/

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var thevalue = $(this).closest("a .includeds")).val();
```

Comment: And the `<a>` element is where? -1